# How to run two different input excel file in common python code using parallel processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have two input excel file (input1 and input2) for common python code. Both are in .xlsx format which need to be consumed by a common single python script. This task to be started at same time in parallel and also need to note which task complete when? How can we solve this kind of situation?

Comment: This question is far too general for StackOverflow. Find some tutorials and get back to us with specific programming problems you hit on the way.

Comment: You can use `multiprocessing` package.

Comment: Have you tried this https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html - this should help u running code in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way too general, does the two process need to talk to each other when working on file? or they just do their own thing? what kind of reporting do you want to see? do you want different line to report for different process? that's gonna be a little difficult to setup. Or do you just want to know when does everything finish?

You can just use simple print for progress report, or check out curses for multi-line screen refresh.

Easiest way to do is just setup two Process, wait for them to finish, and let main process print something to indicate complete.

If you want different Process to talk to each other, you can use multiprocessing.Queue